# Multivariate polynomials division - the case of one divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

It is known that one can divide multivariate polynomials by more divisors and that the result depends on the chosen order. (For example, lex and deglex can produce different results and, of course, different remainders.)
But what if there is only one divisor? Does this phenomenon persist (any example)? Or is there any theorem about a uniqueness of the division of a multivariate polynomial by one divisor?

Answer (score 2):

The "division algorithm" over $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ for $n\geq 2$ still depends on a monomial order (i.e. lex, revlex, etc.) even if you have a single divisor, and unlike the division algorithm for $k[x]$, there is no single canonical ordering.

For instance, if $f(x,y) \in k[x,y]$ and we want to divide by $x-y$, the remainder could be $f(x,x)$ or $f(y,y)$.

Comment: Many thanks. However, is it also possible zero remainder in one monomial order and non-zero in another?

Comment: @Quiriacus No.  If we find that $d$ divides $f$ for some $d,f \in k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ by applying the division algorithm with respect to one monomial order, then we'll conclude that $d$ divides $f$ when applying the division algorithm with respect to any monomial order.  (it's been about 12 years since I've studied Groebner bases, though, so I'm rusty on the details)

Comment: It would be nice to know just this proof. For two divisors, this is no longer true.

Comment: @Quiriacus I had to look this up, but I found an example online of it failing for two divisors. It seems that Groebner bases are defined such that we avoid this problem.  One [arguably heavy-handed] proof, therefore, that it works as I mentioned for a single divisor is just that Buchberger's algorithm for a principal ideal immediately terminates, so the generator of a principal ideal is already a Groebner basis for the ideal.

Comment: If $P=xy+y^5+y^3+y$, $Q_1=x+y^2$, $Q_2=y^4+1$, then $P$ divided by $(Q_1,Q_2)$ gives $(y,y)$ and zero remainder using lex. Using deglex, the remainder is $x^2y+y^3+xy+y$. But back to one divisor: is it really true that zero remainder in one monomial order means zero remainder in any monomial order? It seems it is true.

Comment: Could someone add some references for further reading on this stuff?

Comment: @gen Unfortunately I learned it from my professor's lecture notes rather than a book, so I don't know any references for you.  If you search for monomial orders and Gröbner bases, you'll find some resources online.  If you want to ask for resources, feel free to ask the broader community here for textbook recommendations.